# Converting HEX to DEC is out of range by using `mawk`

Tags: shell, awk, numeric-data

When the hex number is relative small, I can use

```bsh
echo 0xFF| mawk '{ printf "%d\n", $1}'
```

to convert hex to dec.

When then hex number is huge, `mawk` does not work any more, e.g.

```bsh
echo 0x8110D248 | mawk '{ printf "%d\n", $1 }'
```

outputs `2147483647` (which is wrong, `2147483647` is equivalent to `0x7FFFFFFF`).

**How can I convert larger numbers?**

I have a lot of numbers (one number per line, more than 10M) to be processed, e.g: each `0xFF\n 0x1A\n 0x25\n`. How to make it work for such occasion? By `xargs`? Is there any better method? `xargs` is really slow.

Comment: Don't post the same question on multiple sites - https://stackoverflow.com/q/70575244/1745001. See [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted...](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/361691).

Comment: Leaving this one open as it has upvoted answers and I see closure votes starting on the SO one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A better command to use for arbitrarily large numbers is `bc`. Here's a function to perform the conversion

```
hextodec() {
    local hex="${1#0x}"
    printf "ibase=16; %s\n" "${hex^^}" | bc
}

hextodec 0x8110D248
2165363272
```

I'm using a couple of strange-looking features here that manipulate the value of the variables as I use them:

- `"${1#0x}"` - This references `"$1"`, the first parameter to the function, as you would expect. The `#` is a modifier (see `man bash`, for example, or read [POSIX](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html)) that removes the following expression from the front of the value. For example, `0xab12` would be returned as `ab12`
- `"${hex^^}"` - This references `"$hex"` but returns its value with alphabetic characters mapped to uppercase. (This is a `bash` extension, so read `man bash` but not POSIX.) For example, `12ab34` would be returned as `12AB34`

In both cases the `{ … }` curly brackets bind the modifiers to the variable; `"$hex^^"` would have simply returned the value of the `$hex` variable followed by two up-arrow/caret characters

Answer (score 5):

Your issue comes from the fact that `mawk` uses signed 32-bit integers internally, and can therefore not represent integers larger than 2<sup>31</sup>-1 (i.e., 2147483647).

To stream a file with hexadecimal numbers of arbitrary size, converting each to decimal:

```bsh
{
    echo 'ibase=16'
    sed -e 'y/xabcdef/XABCDEF/' -e 's/^0X//'
} | bc
```

This first sends `ibase=16` to `bc`, instructing the utility to read hexadecimal numbers.  Then `sed` is used to convert the hexadcimal letters to upper-case and remove any `0x` prefix on the numbers in the file. We do this since `bc` expects hexadecimal numbers without a `0x` prefix, and with upper-case letters.

Given a file called `file` with the contents

```
0xFF
0x1A
0x25
0x7FFFFFFF
0x8110D248
0x8110D2487FFFFFFF
```

... the pipeline would output

```
255
26
37
2147483647
2165363272
9300164439347036159
```

You could also rewrite the pipeline as a generic streaming shell function:

```
hex2dec () {
    { echo 'ibase=16'; sed -e 'y/xabcdef/XABCDEF/' -e 's/^0X//'; } | bc
}


hex2dec <file

# Or...

some-process-producing-data |
some-filter-extracting-hexadecimal-numbers |
hex2dec |
while IFS= read -r number
    # use the decimal number in "$number" here.
done
```

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas The `y///`-instead-of-`tr` was already part of my answer, but I've made that the only alternative, and incorporated handling both `0X` and `0x`. Thanks.

Comment: D'oh. Sorry, I had missed that.

Comment: @they Why there is a `{}` in `    { echo 'ibase=16'; sed -e 'y/xabcdef/XABCDEF/' -e 's/^0X//'; } `? What's that used for?

Comment: @they Why `hex2dec 0xFF` does not work?Could you please explain that in layman's term for me?

Comment: @John The function reads from standard input, it does not take any arguments. You could still use `hex2dec <<<0xFF` or `echo 0xFF | hex2dec`. You said had lots of numbers to convert, and streaming them all through a single invocation of `bc` rather than starting one `bc` for each number would be much _much_ quicker. So, if you have a file or program that produces hexadecimal numbers, you could pass them through this function in a pipeline, and then read them on the other side.

Comment: @they `hex2dec  <<< 0xFF`? What's `<<<`? Could you please explain that in more detail for me?

Comment: @John It's a "here-string", which is a type of redirection in the `bash` shell (and a few others). It is similar to a "here-document", but only redirects a single string rather than a multi-line document.

Comment: @they Thank you for the detailed clarification.  My last question, which confuses me for a long long time. For roaima's answer, I clear know that the argument passed to `hextodec` is stored by `hex="${1#0x}"`. But for your answer, I really can't find out how the argument(passed to your `hex2dec`) is used( or stored)? Thank you for your attention to this matter.

Comment: @John The function takes no arguments. It reads the numbers from its standard input stream. That's what makes it so efficient and fast, it just passes the input stream over to `bc` and it does a bulk conversion of all numbers in the stream. A here-string is an input redirection, so when you do `hex2dec <<< 0xFF`, it puts the single string `0xFF` on the function's standard input stream. That's rather inefficient, and it would be much more efficient to bulk convert a whole file in one go. You say you have 10M numbers in a file, so doing `hex2dec <thefile` would convert them all in one go.

Comment: @John ... you could then store the output in a new file (`hex2dec <thefile >newfile`), or read it with a `while` loop (like I show in my answer) or something.

Comment: @they " it just ***passes the input stream over to bc*** and it does a bulk conversion of all numbers in the stream."?  Should no the input stream firstly passes to `sed -e 'y/xabcdef/XABCDEF/' -e 's/^0X//'` and then the output of `sed` passes to bc?Is there anything that I misunderstand?

Comment: @John Sorry, I was simplifying to not have to type too much. Yes, the function starts `sed`, which reads from its standard input stream, which it inherits from the function (which the user of the function populates with hexadecimal numbers in some way). The output stream form `sed` is passed to `bc`. Before the output from `sed` arrives to `bc`, `bc` gets the output from `echo` which instructs it to read hexadecimal numbers.

Answer (score 2):

We can use perl's hex() builtin to perform hex -> decimal conversion using the bignum module as suggested by @Stephane Chazelas:

```
$ perl -Mbignum -lpe '$_=hex' file
```

In case all hex numbers are prefixed with 0x or 0X, then we can even use the oct builtin:

```
$ perl -Mbignum -lpe '$_=oct' file
```

We can  use the GNU dc desk calculator , which can read data from file. But before invoking dc, we turn to uppercased hex notation as dc requires it and strip away the leading 0x from the hex string. Then we set the input base to 16 (16i) and just print the number (default is base 10)

```
< file \
tr a-fx A-FX |
cut -d "X" -f 2 |
dc -e "16i [q]sq
[?z0=qpcz0=?]s?
l?x
"
```

---

Using the int() builtin with 16 as second argument, will convert the string of hex digits as first argument, into the equivalent decimal.

```
python3 -c 'import sys
with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
  for l in f:
    print(int(l.strip(),16))
' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Who says mawk can't do it?

```
echo 0x8110D248 | mawk '{OFMT="%.20g";  print +$0 }'

2165363272

% echo 0x8110D248 | mawk '{  printf("%.f\n", $0) }'

2165363272
```

Unlike other variants of AWK, mawk-1.3.4 uses scientific notation past 2³¹-1. The `OFMT` setting circumvents that. At default settings, mawk goes to 2⁵³-1, nawk goes to approx 100-digits, while gawk has no such limitation whatsoever.

Comment: What does 'OFMT="%.20g"'  mean? Could you please explain that in more detail for me?

Comment: F/f specifies forced # of digits past decimal point, without ever using Scientific notation (S.I.). Forcing %.f is equivalent to integer only printing. E/e prints it all with S.I., to full precision specified, even for integers or tail of unneeded trailing zeros. G/g tries balancing both - print true integers up to 20 digits as integer; everything else in S.I.. e.g. :: echo 0x4FEDCBA9876540123  | mawk '{ x = +$0 } { printf(" E : %.20e\n F : %.20f\n G : %.20g\n", x, x, x) }'  | ecp
 
 E : 9.21517348393312583680e+19
 F : 92151734839331258368.00000000000000000000
 G : 92151734839331258368

Answer (score -3):

Regarding the statement

> `mawk` ... therefore not represent integers larger than 2^31-1 (i.e., 2147483647.)

in [the answer by @they](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/684940/377345): this statement is false. You absolutely can read in and print out hex up to double-precision unsigned integer limit, aka 2<sup>53</sup>-1 :

```bash
 echo '0x1234BEEF9CAFE7' \
 \
 | mawk '{ CONVFMT=OFMT="%.20g"; 
       print a=+(       substr($0,1,length($0)-8)),\
             b=+(("0x")(substr($0,1+length($0)-8))),\
             c=2^32*a+b,\
             sprintf("0x%X%.8X",a,b) }'

1193150 4020023271 5124544249245671 0x1234BEEF9CAFE7
```

or the even safer approach - split it 16<sup>7</sup> on high side, 16<sup>6</sup> on low side :

```bash
echo '0x1234BEEF9CAFE7' | mawk '{ CONVFMT=OFMT="%.20g"; OFS="\f"; n=length(x=$0)
print a=+(       substr(x,1,n-6)),
      b=+(("0x")(substr(x,1+n-6))),
      c=2^24*a+b,
      sprintf("0x%X%.6X",a,b) }'
 
305446639
         10268647
                 5124544249245671
                                 0x1234BEEF9CAFE7
```

Here's the more generic version where you can simply tweak the `ndigits` parameter for how many hex digits you want on the low side :

```bash
 echo '0x1234BEEF9CAFE7' \
  \
  | mawk '{ CONVFMT=OFMT="%.20g"; 
            OFS="\f"; 

            w=length(x=$0); ndigits=7; # enter 6, 7, or 8

print a=+(       substr(x,1,w-ndigits)),
      b=+(("0x")(substr(x,1+w-ndigits))),
      c=(16^ndigits)*a+b,
      sprintf("0x%X%.*X",a,ndigits,b) }'

19090414
        261926887
                 5124544249245671
                                 0x1234BEEF9CAFE7
```

10M rows should be very quick. I created a random test file of 55.78 million rows of hex, each with 13 hex digits:

```bash
 % echo; ( time (  pvE0 < test_hex_list_01.txt| mawk 'BEGIN { CONVFMT=OFMT="%.20g"; const16=16^(ndigits=7) } { printf("%.f\n",const16*(a=+substr(x=$0,1,(w=length(x))-ndigits))+(b=+("0x"substr(x,1+w-ndigits))),a,ndigits,b) }' )) | pvE9 > test_hex_list_01_output_mawk_short.txt ; echo  

     out9: 2.22MiB 0:00:00 [22.1MiB/s] [22.1MiB/s] [<=>                                ]
      in0:  851MiB 0:00:39 [21.5MiB/s] [21.5MiB/s] [=================>] 100%            
     out9:  887MiB 0:00:39 [22.6MiB/s] [22.4MiB/s] [  <=>                              ]
( pvE 0.1 in0 < test_hex_list_01.txt | mawk ; )  39.20s user 0.94s system 101% cpu 39.64     out9:  887MiB 0:00:39 [22.4MiB/s] [22.4MiB/s] [ <=>                               ]
    
 % awkwc5 < test_hex_list_01.txt 
    
rows       = 55,779,444. | UTF8 chars = 892,471,099. | bytes      = 892,471,099.
```

It barely took 39.2 seconds to finish nearly 56 million rows of hex.